# Translation length on annular curve graphs

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, mapping-class-groups

Question about curve stabilisers acting on annular curve graphs, plus context since I'm interested in being fact-checked.

**Definition:** let the group $G$ act by isometries on a metric space $(X,d)$.  The *stable translation length* of $g\in G$ is $\tau(g) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(x,g^nx)/n$, (for any $x\in X$).

**Context:** if $S$ is a connected, oriented, hyperbolic surface of sufficiently high finite complexity, and $C(S)$ is its curve graph, then the action of the mapping class group $MCG(S)$ on $C(S)$ is acylindrical, and this implies the existence of $K>0$, depending on $S$, such that $\tau(g)\geq K$ for $g$ pseudo-Anosov (Theorem 1.3 and Lemma 2.2 in [Bowditch](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgak/papers/bhb-tight.pdf)).

My question is about **annular** subsurfaces of $S$.  Fix an isotopy class $\gamma$ of essential simple closed curves, and let $G < MCG(S)$ be the stabiliser of $\gamma$.

Let $C(\gamma)$ be the curve graph of the annulus in $S$ with core curve $\gamma$, defined in Section 2.4 of [Masur and Minsky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9807150.pdf), where it is explained that $C(\gamma)$ is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb R$, and $G$ acts by isometries, and the Dehn twist $t$ satisfies $\tau(t) =1$ for this action.

**Question:**  Does there exist $K>0$ (allowed to depend on $S$) such that the $G$--action on $C(\gamma)$ has the property that for all $g\in G$, either $\tau(g)=0$ or $\tau(g)>K$?

I tentatively guess "no" but I don't know an argument.

On the other hand, I don't think one can use the above result about acylindricity to say "yes": I believe it's well-known (and seems fairly straightforward) that the image $\bar G$ of $G$ in $Isom(C(\gamma))$ does not in general act acylindrically on $C(\gamma)$. Actually, I also struggle to find a reference for non-acylindricity of $\bar G$ on $C(\gamma)$; is there one or is this MCG folklore?

(My coauthors and I have a result which is "sharp" given a "no" to the question, we're writing the introduction to the paper, and want to comment on MCGs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer is “yes, such a constant $K$ exists.”

Suppose that $g$ is the given mapping class in the stabiliser of  $\gamma$. Replace $g$ by a large power (bounded by the topology of $S$) so that it fixes the curves of its canonical reducing system (and also their orientations and their sides).  In each component of the complement of the reducing system, this new $g$ acts as either the identity, or as a pseudo-Anosov map.

If we only have the former, $g$ is a product of powers of disjoint Dehn twists, and we are done.

If we have some of the latter, then we take a further power (again bounded by the topology of $S$) so that $g$ fixes the switches of its stable train-tracks.  In particular, we can control the hyperbolic geometry of a neighbourhood of $\gamma$.  The action of $g$ on arcs of $C(\gamma)$ sends endpoints into the “cusps” of the stable track, and otherwise does a power of a Dehn twist. The motion of the endpoints (once close enough to the cusps) is sufficiently slow that it does not contribute to the stable translation length, and we are done.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to estimate the stable translation length by using an element of the arc complex which goes straight to a cusp on both sides of $\gamma$. It follows that (this further power of) $g$ has integer valued stable translation length, just like a Dehn twist.